# Extracting columns having greater than certain values in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
Alix    Blim    Jux Gyno
0.105   0.234   0.67    0.89
0.01    0.542   0.11    0.65
0.003   0.002   0.6     0.67
0.009   0.123   0.09    0.01
```

From the above dataframe, I will like to extract all columns having values greater than 0.6 as below:

```
Jux Gyno
0.67    0.89
0.11    0.65
0.6     0.67
0.09    0.01
```

Here's my code that didn't work:

```
out <- vector()

for(i in colnames(df){
  if(df[i] > 0.6){
     T <- df[,i]
  }
  out <- cbind.data.frame(out,T)
}
```

I got an error like:

```
Error in data.frame(Check.names= F...). Argument imply differing number of rows.....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `colSums` to subset columns using base R

```
df[colSums(df > 0.6) > 0]

# Jux Gyno
#1 0.67 0.89
#2 0.11 0.65
#3 0.60 0.67
#4 0.09 0.01
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select_if(~any(. > 0.6))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- read.table(text='Alix    Blim    Jux Gyno
0.105   0.234   0.67    0.89
0.01    0.542   0.11    0.65
0.003   0.002   0.6     0.67
0.009   0.123   0.09    0.01
', header=T)
```

We can use `sapply` to find the max value in each column, then check if it's greater than 0.6. This gives a logical vector which we can use to subset `df` by column:

```
df[,sapply(df, max) > 0.6]

   Jux Gyno
1 0.67 0.89
2 0.11 0.65
3 0.60 0.67
4 0.09 0.01
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a `base R` option with `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) any(x > 0.6), df)
#  Jux Gyno
#1 0.67 0.89
#2 0.11 0.65
#3 0.60 0.67
#4 0.09 0.01
```

---

Or using `transmute_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    transmute_if(~ any(.x > 0.6), I)
```

Or with `keep`

```
library(purrr)
keep(df, map_lgl(df, ~ any(.x > 0.6)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> df[ , sapply(df, function(x) any(x>0.6))]
   Jux Gyno
1 0.67 0.89
2 0.11 0.65
3 0.60 0.67
4 0.09 0.01
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for fantastic solutions!. All solutions worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide a reproducible example for future questions.

Here is my dplyr solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(First = 0:5,
             Second = 10:15,
             Third = 20:25)

is_greater_than <- function(x) any(x > 10)

select_if(df, is_greater_than)
```